# How to find the sum using the Maclaurin Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

How to find the sum of using the Maclaurin Series.

$\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }\frac{ (-1)^ k(\pi^{2k+1}) } {(4^{2k+1})(2k+1)!}$

I got the answer as $1/\sqrt { 2 } $

Can anyone please verify whether this is correct or no

Comment: $\sum _{ k=0 }^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^k x^{2k+1} } {(2k+1)!}$ is the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$, so that your numerical series has the value $\sin(\pi/4)=1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Yes, I used maclaurin series and compared it to sin(x). then here x=pi/4.   I substituted x in sin(x) and got the answer. Can you just verify whether it is correct or not

Comment: That is correct since Maclaurin series of $\sin x$ converges for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So, the answer is $1/\sqrt { 2 } $ right